# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '!' using jquery, dataTables and ajax

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a script witch is using dataTables and an Ajax call for data.
The script in general works fine but I would like to catch a zero data return and if zero, open a modal.

But the script generates an error, see below. Can anyone see where I am going wrong.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '!'

```
rowCallback: function(row, data, index){
  $('td', row).attr('nowrap','nowrap');
  if(data.Signage == 2 || data.Signage == 1 ){
    $('#SignageOn').show();
  } else if (data.Signage == 0) {
    $('#SignageOn').hide();
  }
  $(row).find('td:eq(3)').css('color', '#009900');
  $(row).find('td:eq(4)').css('color', '#CC0000');
  if (!$.trim(data)){ // Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '!'
    // do something
  }
},
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have properly copied the code here? `!$.trim(data)` seems to be syntactically correct.

Comment: @LajosArpad I am using the same !$.trim(data) outside of the "callback" in another part of the script and the syntax works fine. It's just not working within the "callback". Basically what it should do is check to see if data contains data returned by the Ajax call used for populating a dataTables table.

Comment: Can you debug the issue and check whether there are ways of reproducing it?